# s3cmd get an entire directory

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd

I have a directory in my s3 that has only another directory inside it, but I don't know it's name. Using command line "get" tools, i'd like to download that directory, but it doesn't seems to want to.

The structure looks like:

`my-production/top-dir/sub-dir/some-files.jpg`

then

`s3cmd get  s3://my-production/top-dir/* local-dir`

The "sub-dir" directory does not download. 
Do I have to get the directory name, make the directory locally, then "get" all it's contents?

Answer (score 59):

You have to pass parameter `--recursive` eg. `s3cmd get --recursive s3://my-production/top-dir/ local-dir`.

Answer (score 1):

aws s3 sync s3://bucket-name my-local-dir

Answer (score -2):

you have to use "sync" instead of "get"

Comment: nope, spoke to soon, you really have to pay attention to the paths.   s3cmd get --recursive --force s3://bucket/subdirwithothersubdirsinit/ localbucket/subdirwithothersubdirsinit/ will pull all files and "subdirectories" .